# What are some of the best books for a robust introduction to Logic and Critical Thinking?

Tags: logic, reference-request

As the question states:

**What are some of the best books for a robust introduction to Logic and Critical Thinking?**

My background:

I'm 24, graduating with two degrees in Political Science and International Relations with extensive works in Economics.

I am learning to program and I would like a more solid base for my critical thinking and logical argument composition, in order to make my programming skills more concise.

However, I believe that in order for me to achieve this, I need to start with the basics of logic first.

Which books do you recommend?

Comment: Maybr useful [Informal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-informal/) with Biblio.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA this is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First book to self-learn logic, mainly to improve reading comprehension?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/first-book-to-self-learn-logic-mainly-to-improve-reading-comprehension)